# DTD is not allowed in XML fragments - xml into sql

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I am trying to save XML into database using stored procedure and in asp.net I am using...

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@input", SqlDbType.Xml).Value = new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml(new XmlTextReader(returnXML.InnerXml, XmlNodeType.Document, null));
```

and this returns an error

> DTD is not allowed in XML fragments

Anyone please suggest, thank you.

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using? Why do you want to store it as a XML? Do you need to just store it or you want to use SQL methods which allows you to work with XML?

Comment: sql 2005, m not storing whold xml, but looping through nodes to insert rows in a table.

Comment: You could remove the doctype declaration before assigning to a XML variable or you could use [openxml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx) to shred the XML.

Comment: You could use a nvarchar(max) parameter and convert to a local XML variable using style 2. `@xml = convert(xml, @Param, 2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed - 'remove the doctype declaration before assigning to a XML variable' - Mikael Eriksson

```
XmlDocumentType XDType = returnXML.DocumentType;
returnXML.RemoveChild(XDType);
Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml(new XmlTextReader(returnXML.InnerXml, XmlNodeType.Document, null));
```